# How to set the background image of all windows in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I want to set the background image of all windows and style of all data grids in all windows of my wpf application in a single place

I have the following code in my app.xaml file

```
<Application.Resources>

    <!--Styles for woindow-->
    <ImageBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroungImage" ImageSource="Icons\clinic.jpg"/>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="WindowBorderBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0" >
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <!--Styles for Data Grid-->
    <Style x:Key="DGCHeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight"  Value="SemiBold" />
        <!--<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />-->
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DataGridRowBackground" EndPoint="195.5,455" StartPoint="195.5,0" MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF0FC9E6" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF6CA3AC"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="DataGridAlternatingRowBackground" SpreadMethod="Reflect" Center="195.5,227.5" GradientOrigin="195.5,227.5" MappingMode="Absolute" RadiusY="227.5" RadiusX="195.5">
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFEEA21F" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF7F3E9"/>
    </RadialGradientBrush>

    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DGCHeaderStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="{StaticResource DataGridRowBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="{StaticResource DataGridAlternatingRowBackground}" />
    </Style>

    <!--Settin window style-->
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource WindowBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroungImage}"/>
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

The style of DataGrid is applied as desired in designer and also when i start debugging
The background image appears in designer in visual studio as desired but it is not shown in any window when i start the application in debugging mode.

when I add the following lines in 'mainwindow.xaml' file the background image appears as desired

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush  ImageSource="Icons\clinic.jpg"/>
</Window.Background>
```

I have an icons folder in my project in which the background image is placed with the name of clinic.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not issue with your ImageBrush, rather you cannot set any property by default style using the base type `Window` here. Reason is your Window is of type `MainWindow` not `Window`. Hence it does not work. If you give your Window Type you will be able to set it for that window.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource WindowBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroungImage}"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

So basically you will have to define style for all your window types. You can define one style and can simply create others using `BasedOn`

```
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource WindowBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroungImage}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"/>
```

Comment: please explain how to use BasedOn

Comment: But i want to be able to set the background image of all windows using a single style

Comment: you cannot have single default style for all your custom window. Either you will have to create different styles like I explained in answer or  have a single style with `x:Key` and apply that style to all windows by setting `Window.Style`

Comment: vs says  the namespace prefix "local" is not defined

Comment: you will have to add it `<Application x:Class="WpfApplication2.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">` Add your namespace here