# WPF window's background color is not set by style automatically

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created simple WPF application with one window. What I want is to apply background color automatically to all windows. However, the color isn't applied.
Here's [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/msjo2ay73md9y8m/SampleWPFApp.zip?dl=0) to sample project. The following is XAML in App:

```
<Application x:Class="SampleWPFApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleWPFApp"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF3B444B" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="local:MainWindow" BasedOn="{StaticResource Window}" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The logic was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36679108/how-to-set-the-background-image-of-all-windows-in-wpf-application).

**EDIT:**

Well, I wasn't a bit fare about *when* the background isn't set - it's not set in VS editor. When program runs, background is OK. The solutions of Ragavan and mm8 *do* work, albeit they are the same with the difference that `BasedOn="{StaticResource Window}"` lets us omit the style's key (being `Window` the key itself).

Alas, the editor doesn't show the background, although setting the style explicitly (in MainWindow's XAML) makes background appear.

Answer (score 3):

Basedon Will not bind directly window . Replace this code   `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"`

**App.Xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="SampleWPFApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleWPFApp"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF3B444B" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="local:MainWindow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Does it work for you? If it does, could you share the project?

Comment: i just downloaded your solution and changed

Comment: I used your code - still no result. Here's [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/msjo2ay73md9y8m/SampleWPFApp.zip?dl=0) to second project file.

Comment: i downloaded this file , remains same code , not changed code

Comment: Sorry, here's correct [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdzp7uekipc5hn/SampleWPFApp2.zip?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

1. In WPF, you set the styling resource for a type and not for an instance of type. Hence, below line should be removed.

> Style TargetType="local:MainWindow" BasedOn="{StaticResource Window}" />

2. In your case, Windows background is being applied but it is just not visible because it may have a panel within. For example, when you create a new window, it will have Grid by default. Add below line and you will get the background for entire window. Please append &LT character in the below lines.

> &LTStyle TargetType="{x:Type Grid}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
>   &LTSetter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
>   &LT/Style>

Comment: All this didn't help. I removed Grid - still no result.

Comment: My solution will work with a Grid inside a window. I am wrong about Windows background. I have voted up the other solution by Ragavan and is exactly what is needed for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just give your style an `x:Key` and base the `MainWindow` style on this one. This works wonders for me:

```
<Application x:Class="SampleWPFApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleWPFApp"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myWindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF3B444B" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="local:MainWindow" BasedOn="{StaticResource myWindowStyle}" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work! Here's third app [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dn9208spdkdu3xn/SampleWPFApp3.zip?dl=0) using your code. Which version of Visual Studio do you use? I use VS 2017 RC (15.0.0-RC.4+26206.0).

Comment: It works for me in VS 2015 when I build against .NET Framework 4.6.1.